# Chrome UI issue - Al setear la cutlurización de mi Web .NET, los números no son mostrados en los inputs al tener el formato XX,XXX

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Necesito setear mi sistema a una cultura de Argentina para que los textos y el símbolo de moneda sea el correcto pero al setear el Web.config de la siguiente manera:

`<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" uiCulture="auto" culture="es-AR" />`

Estoy recibiendo el siguiente mensaje *'The specified value "XX,XX" cannot be parsed, or is out of range'* al cambiar la culturización de mi sistema  y los inputs con decimales se muestran vacíos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya que al mostrar determinados valores como Currency, en vez de utilizar el símbolo $, usa "XDR", Euros o demás.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, si dejo el uiCulture="auto" y culture="auto" funciona todo bien pero dependiendo de qué navegador abra, me va a mostrar un distinto tipo de símbolo en mis listados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Básicamente resolví el problema agregando el siguiente código al Global.asax:

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    }
```

Si bien el sistema está en Español, tuve que forzar el UI a inglés para no tener problemas con los decimales.